# how could I use useEffect() in Class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to use `useEffect()`to instead of `componentWillMount()`, but I found the hook can not use in class components, so I change the code as Function component, but it will get more error for the whole component, all code with this.xxx are getting an error, how could I edit below code to make it work? it was not easy for the react beginner. Please help me.
Below code is working fine with `componentWillMount()`.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../../assets/images/logo.png';
import './index.less';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import menuList from '../../config/menuConfig';

const { SubMenu } = Menu;
class LeftNav extends Component {
  getMenuNodes = menuList => {
    const path = this.props.location.pathname;
    return menuList.reduce((pre, item) => {
      if (!item.children) {
        pre.push(
          <Menu.Item key={item.key} icon={item.icon}>
            <Link to={item.key}>{item.title}</Link>
          </Menu.Item>,
        );
      } else {
        const cItem = item.children.find(cItem => cItem.key === path);
        if (cItem) {
          this.openKey = item.key;
        }
        pre.push(
          <SubMenu key={item.key} icon={item.icon} title={item.title}>
            {this.getMenuNodes(item.children)}
          </SubMenu>,
        );
      }
      return pre;
    }, []);
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.MenuNodes = this.getMenuNodes(menuList);
  }
  render () {
     //   useEffect(() => {
      //this.MenuNodes = this.getMenuNodes(menuList);
   // }, []);
    const path = this.props.location.pathname;
    console.log(path);
    const openKey = this.openKey;
    return (
      <div className="left-nav">
        <Link to="./" className="left-nav-header">
          <img src={logo} alt="" />
          <h1>Backend System</h1>
        </Link>
        <Menu
          selectedKeys={[path]}
          defaultOpenKeys={[openKey]}
          mode="inline"
          theme="dark"
        >
          {this.MenuNodes}
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(LeftNav);
```

Comment: hooks remove `this`, please read the docs carefully before switching from classfull component to  classless component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a stab at refactoring your class component into a functional component using hooks. In the end I found that instead of the `useEffect` hook, it was better to use the `useMemo` hook. `useMemo` is used to memoize expensive calculations, in this case, the calculation of menuNodes and openKey. `useMemo` will run anytime it's dependencies change, in this case, `[menuList, path]`.

You will also notice that instead of the withRouter Higher-Order-Component, I replaced it with a call to the `useLocation` hook from 'react-router-dom'.

Let me know if this works for you, and if you have any questions.

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../../assets/images/logo.png';
import './index.less';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import menuList from '../../config/menuConfig';

const LeftNav = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const path = location.pathname;

  const { MenuNodes, openKey } = useMemo(() => {
    let openKey;

    const getMenuNodes = (menuList) => {
      return menuList.reduce((pre, item) => {
        if (!item.children) {
          pre.push(
            <Menu.Item key={item.key} icon={item.icon}>
              <Link to={item.key}>{item.title}</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          );
        } else {
          const cItem = item.children.find((cItem) => cItem.key === path);
          if (cItem) {
            openKey = item.key;
          }
          pre.push(
            <Menu.SubMenu key={item.key} icon={item.icon} title={item.title}>
              {getMenuNodes(item.children)}
            </Menu.SubMenu>
          );
        }
        return pre;
      }, []);
    };

    const nodes = getMenuNodes(menuList);

    return { MenuNodes: nodes, openKey: openKey };
  }, [path]);

  return (
    <div className="left-nav">
      <Link to="./" className="left-nav-header">
        <img src={logo} alt="" />
        <h1>Backend System</h1>
      </Link>
      <Menu selectedKeys={[path]} defaultOpenKeys={[openKey]} mode="inline" theme="dark">
        {MenuNodes}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LeftNav;
```

#### edit

Fixed recursive call in getMenuNodes

Comment: thanks, i have copied your code to instead my code, but it does not work.

Comment: error 'Line 29:14:  'getMenuNodes' is not defined  no-undef '

Comment: @Keida ah, okay. I missed the recursion part. I've updated the code above with a fix. I believe it should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, i have removed the menuList in useMemo((){},[menuList,path]) as the warning shows React Hook useMemo has an unnecessary dependency: 'menuList'. Either exclude it or
it or remove the dependency array.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, since menuList is defined outside of the component.

Answer (score 3):

componentDidMount() is the lifecycle method you want to use, it can be compared to useEffect you use in functional components. componentWillMount() is deprecated and you should not use it.